# Cross List Data View Web Part Data source Problem

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, data-view-web-part

I have Created a List across parent site and all Sub Sites ,and I want to rollup all list data using DVWP . How to do this with List data source

Answer (score 1):

1.Create a web part page ,add empty data view web part, go to data source and select the list on which we want to create rollup .
2. Change DataSourceMode from List to CrossList.
3. add <Webs Scope="Recursive"></Webs> just after SelectCommand= at line number 40
4 .replace LIst GUID with List name.

Thank You for your help

Answer (score 0):

As the sites are in the same site collection, you can save the list as a web part to the web part gallery and add it in another site using SharePoint Designer.

1. Open the list in SharePoint Designer.
2. Open one of the views in detailed view by clicking the view hyperlink.
3. Click the 'Web Part' tab and choose Save Web Part 'To Site Gallery'.
4. "Do you want this Web Part to always show list data from the current web site…", Click ‘Yes’.
5. Go to the site where you need to display the library, edit the page, click the ‘Insert’ tab and then browse to the ‘Miscellaneous’ folder. You will find your list view web part available to be added to the page.

A demo: [Displaying SharePoint lists to parent or sub-sites](http://blog.cloudbusiness.com/the-company/blog-and-news/displaying-sharepoint-online-2013-lists-to-parent-or-sub-sites) (also works in SP 2013)

Comment: I am trying to create a Cross List Dataview web part , so that where ever I am adding this dvwp , I want to show all the list data from current site and its sub sites. I will check your answer and update you. but here my doubt is why I am unable to see my list under data source of the dvwp

Comment: Hi JoannaW_MSFT,

Comment: Hi Jonna, my problem is fixed now. with these changes 1. Change DataSourceMode from List to CrossList.
2. add &lt;Webs Scope=&quot;Recursive&quot;&gt;&lt;/Webs&gt; just after SelectCommand= at line number 40
3.replace LIst GUID with List name. 

Thank You for your help

Comment: Thanks for sharing. You can "accept" your answer as the best answer.